# Too many CronJob Processes

Tags: file-io, process, cron

I am facing a problem that i really can not explain. I spent days to find out what the problem is but i am becoming mad now.

I have build a Web Application that needs some cronjobs to run. **The current cronjob of the www-data** is the following:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/cronjob.php
```

root user does not have any cronjob (just to mention that).

The cronjobs runs fine every minute. But somehow it does not close properly or something. My Processes List is the following:

http://pastebin.com/zYKGWLWF

As you can see the cronjob.php remains open and takes all the memory. What i CAN NOT UNDERSTAND is that if i run the cronjob manual it works fine and it ends in just some seconds.

What is really strange also, is that when i reboot the machine, the cronjobs are running fine without leaving a fork behind. This is only happening if the machine remains open for some hours.

What can I do about this?